# Vue core UI different menu for different user

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, core-ui

I am using the Vue core UI admin template. There is a file called _nav.js which basically exports an array. I am saving into vuex.a userrole array. An example of a role would be admin or dashboard.

In the sidebar menu I only want to display the dashboard item from the _nav.js file if they have the dashboard userrole.
I have tried changing the _nav.js file to check the store but the sidebar  renders before the userrole are set and when the userrole are set in the store the sidebar doesn't rerender. The routing is separate I just need to know about the menu item display.

Has anyone got experience of this.vue coreui template and could direct me in how to achieve my goal.

Comment: so your question is how to get sidebar to be rendered only after you have userrole?

Comment: Yes or to force it to rerender , I'm new to Vue so don't fully understand it all yet. Thanks